# Retrieving records in a date range using Grails + Joda-Time

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm, jodatime

I am trying to retrieve a list of events using the following code

```
 def startDay = new DateTime().withDayOfMonth(1)
 def endDay = new DateTime().dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue()
 def eventsList = <Domain Class>.findAllEventDateBetween(startDay..endDay)
```

I have specified the following in the domain class

```
static mapping = {
    eventDate type: PersistentDateTime
}
```

From what I have been able to find, I thought this would return a list of event records between the two date times i specified. However I get the following error whenever I try to run the code

```
    Method expression 'Between' requires 2 arguments. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Method expression 'Between' requires 2 arguments
    Line | Method
->>  111 | methodMissing in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     19 | doCall        in koss.SomeController$_closure3$$EOPB7E85
|    195 | doFilter . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter      in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I doing anything right?

I just want to retrieve a set of records that are from the current month. Unfortunately I cant seem to find anything more that can help me.

Comment: Have you tried using a Criteria query instead of the dynamic method approach?http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withCriteria.html

Comment: Thanks @derdc , It worked like a charm. +1 for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 def eventsList = <Domain Class>.findAllEventDateBetween(startDay, endDay)
```

error says it pretty clearly, dynamic finder between requires two arguments, not a range

Comment: I'm a little new to this so could you tell me what exactly the the arguments list would look like? Because in plain old Java that clearly is two arguments.Also, I would like to point out, what you have written is not an answer. A comment would have been more acceptable.

Comment: He's right, it should be two arguments. You were passing a range with the .. notation, which is a different thing entirely.

Comment: If your question was "What am I doing wrong? Am I doing anything right?", my answer is fine in my opinion because it clearly says what are you doing wrong and how to do it right.